# 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' Error in my React website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm using a **useEffect** hook inside my React component which is updating a local state when there is any change in global redux state.

This is my component which is trying to update imgList when we gets updated photos using useSelector. But the website is crashing due to the error '**Maximum call stack size exceeded**'.
useEffect is running again and again which shouldn't happen since photos only gets updated once.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { fetchDataHandler } from "./store/actions";

const PhotoWrapper = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [imgList, setImgList] = useState([]);
  const photos = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state.data }));
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchDataHandler());
  }, [dispatch]);

/* useEffect which is causing website crashing */

  useEffect(() => {
    const topImages = photos[0]?.map((photo) => (
      <img src={photo?.url} alt={photo?.title} />
    ));
    setImgList(() => topImages);
  }, [photos]);
  return <div>{imgList}</div>;
};

export default PhotoWrapper;
```

Here is the link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-thunk-basics-bpsbz1?file=/src/PhotoWrapper.js:0-638) to generate error.

Comment: I don't see why you need `const [imgList, setImgList] = useState([]);` here. Why not just map or do it in `useMemo`? https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-thunk-basics-forked-3xcxrm?file=/src/PhotoWrapper.js

Comment: we can. But suppose we have a huge application and we are getting 5000 images. I want to store only 10 of them and then can pass it as a prop instead of calculating it from global state again and again.  Similarly in some other pages, we can have a requirement to show 20 images. Basically, Just want to understand the reason for it.

Comment: `useMemo`? https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-thunk-basics-forked-o93ccu?file=/src/PhotoWrapper.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except that you shouldn't really map JSX inside the `useEffect`, the problem is that you are spreading the information from the store.

```
const photos = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state.data }));
                                     // ^^^^^^^^^
```

So with every re-render, you have a different *instance* of `photos` (because of spread) and you are ending up with an *infinite loop*.

Just remove the spread to get rid of the error.

```
const photos = useSelector((state) => state.data);
```

Comment: Yes. was looking for the reason. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code to the following:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDataHandler } from './store/actions';

const PhotoWrapper = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const photos = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchDataHandler());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      {photos[0]?.map((photo) => (
        <img src={photo?.url} alt={photo?.title} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PhotoWrapper;
```

Or to this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDataHandler } from './store/actions';

const PhotoWrapper = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [imgList, setImgList] = useState([]);
  const photos = useSelector((state) => state.data);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchDataHandler());
  }, [dispatch]);

  /* useEffect which is causing website crashing */

  useEffect(() => {
    const topImages = photos[0]?.map((photo) => ({ url: photo?.url, title: photo?.title }));
    setImgList(() => topImages);
  }, [JSON.stringify(photos)]);

  return (
    <div>
      {imgList.map((el, i) => (
        <img key={i} src={el?.url} alt={el?.title} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PhotoWrapper;
```